# Selective formatting of items in \printbibliography - Perform \bibcheck in \defbibenvironment?

Tags: biblatex, filter

I would like to change the style of single references selectively when using \printbibliography so I can highlight featured publications.

1. Is there an elegant way to do that using a library?
2. If not, how can I make this snipped of code work?

In particular, how do I define a filter over a *custom field* in biblatex?

And how can I apply this filter in an if-condition within the *defbibenvironment*?

```
  \defbibcheck{featuredPublications}{
%  TODO: filter according to custom field feature=true
}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\inparaitem}
  {\unspace\endinparaitem}
  {\ifthenelse{\boolean{\bibcheck{featuredPublications}}} % <-- This does not work!! 
    {\item \faStar}
    {\item}
   }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bibchecks are only used to filter bibliography lists, i.e. to control which entries are shown and not shown in a bibliography list. They cannot be used to influence the formatting of entries in the bibliography. But bibchecks are just built from ordinary `biblatex` macros that you can use directly if you want to format stuff.

One very simple way to mark up particular entries as special is via entry options. Entry options are given in the `options` field, so this isn't exactly the syntax you had in mind in your question, but the advantage is that this works without defining a custom field in a custom data model, so it's much less overhead.

The usual way is to have the option set a toggle which you can test later.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newtoggle{bbx:featured}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{feature}[true]{\settoggle{bbx:featured}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iftoggle{bbx:featured}
    {\faStar}
    {}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  options   = {feature=true},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Two entries, one with a star.]

---

If you insist on a custom field, here is how that could go

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{filecontents}{featured.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{feature}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields{feature}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, datamodel=featured]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \iffieldequalstr{feature}{true}
    {\faStar}
    {}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
  feature   = {true},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

The usual way to give a list of entry keys of entries with a certain property in the `.tex` file is via bibliography categories.

First you declare a new category with `\DeclareBibliographyCategory`. Then you can add entries to a category with `\addtocategory`, which accepts a comma-separated lists of entry keys in its second argument.
In bibmacros you can check if an entry belongs to a category with `\ifcategory`. Bibliographies can easily be filtered by category (without a bibcheck) using the `category` option.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{featured}
\addtocategory{featured}{elk,worman,geer}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \ifcategory{featured}
    {\faStar}
    {}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  publisher = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location  = {London},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Quick follow up, is there a way to filter by a list of citation keys? That would make my life much easier.

Comment: @FrustratedAcademic In that case use a category. See the edit, please.

Comment: Cheers! Thank you so much for the excellent explanation!